# Using AND/OR operators in filter string

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have an on_click event on a form that then opens up another form with a set criteria. The code is as follows:

```
Private Sub cmdProjectList_Click()
Dim stDocName As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String

stDocName = "Project List"
strCriteria = "([PLeadID] = " & TempVars!CurrentUserID & " Or [BLeadID] = " & TempVars!CurrentUserID & " OR [OwnerID] = " & TempVars!CurrentUserID & ") AND [Sensitivity] >= " & Me.txtaccesslevel & ""


If Me.txtaccesslevel = 1 Or Me.txtaccesslevel = 5 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName
    Forms(stDocName).FilterOn = False
    Forms(stDocName).Requery
ElseIf Me.txtaccesslevel <> 1 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName
    Forms(stDocName).Filter = strCriteria
    Forms(stDocName).FilterOn = True
    Forms(stDocName).Requery
End If


End Sub
```

The criteria works if I edit it so that only one criteria is being used at a time, however whenever I add multiple using the OR/AND operators it seems only the last criteria takes effect (sensitivity). I am sure it is a simple syntax error but I have tried a few things with no luck.

EDIT: The value I am changing in order to get the correct filtering is `strCriteria`. The If statement with the `Me.txtaccesslevel` works perfectly, however after opening the form (project list) it is the `Forms(stDocName).Filter=strCriteria` line that is causing the issue. Like I said if I reduced the `strCriteria` value to only be `"[PLeadID]= " &TempVars!CurrentUserID &""` it works it is when I try to string all the criteria together using OR/AND that it does not work.

EDIT 2: Adding in the line `Debug.Print strCriteria` outputs the message: `([PLeadID] = 40 Or [BLeadID] = 40 OR [OwnerID] = 40) AND [Sensitivity] >= 4`. The values it outputs are all correct and I checked the filter that can be viewed on the property sheet of the form in design mode and it displays the exact same line.

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain a little further, where do you edit this to get it to work as expected? `If Me.txtaccesslevel = 1 Or Me.txtaccesslevel = 5 Then` or `ElseIf Me.txtaccesslevel <> 1 Then` ?

Comment: @JimmySmith edited above for clarification.

Comment: Please add a line `Debug.Print strCriteria` after assigning it, and add the output (Ctrl+G shows it) for a non-working case to your question. You might even see the problem immediately yourself.

Comment: And are you sure that there are records with [Sensitivity] >= 4, that have neither [PLeadID] = 40 nor [BLeadID] = 40 nor [OwnerID] = 40 ? -- The filter string looks ok.

Comment: @madelina you have a variable `TempVars!CurrentUserID` ? this can't be, the VB will not allow you to have a `!` inside a variable